# SQL How to check group by for multiple values in jpa query syntax

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have a database table that looks like this:

```html
<style type="text/css">
 table.tableizer-table {
 border: 1px solid #CCC; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
} 
.tableizer-table td {
 padding: 4px;
 margin: 3px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.tableizer-table th {
 background-color: #104E8B; 
 color: #FFF;
 font-weight: bold;
}
</style><table class="tableizer-table">
<tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>id</th><th>contactList</th><th>customer</th></tr>
 <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>9</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>9</td></tr>
 <tr><td>3</td><td>2</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

I have a JPA query that I can't figure out.  It currently looks like this:

```
select o.customer.id from ContactListMember o where o.contactList.id = 2 and o.contactList.id = 3
```

I know this isn't right.  I'm trying to get it to return a single customerId when that customerId has a record with a contactList = 2 and it has a record with a contactList = 3.  So in this case I need the query to return the customerId of 9 and not customerId 1.